# MySQL truncates my first zeros data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL column "phone" , and when data comes from my php form, if there's a zero at the beginning, it will disappear in the table, for example : 
"**06719823**" becomes "**6719823**"

I first though it was a problem from php, cause I'm using mysql_real_escape_string(), but then I tried to modify the SQL field directly on phpmyadmin, and I can't add a first 0, it always delete it.

```
Colonne     Type     Interclassement    Attributs   Null    Défaut  Extra
phone       int(10)                                 Oui     NULL
```

What's wrong ? Should I assign an "interclassement" **utf8_general_ci** ?

Comment: Phone numbers are strings, not integers. Change your datatype.

Comment: Thanks, varchar(10) worked just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your column type to `char(10)` for 10 digit phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If the column type is int (integer), **the number will be internally represented as an integer**, meaning "first 0s" won't be stored, as they hold no meaning for integers.

Since what you are actually trying to store has meaning as **a sequence of characters**, and not as a quantity, it would make more sense to store it as a **char(n)**, for n-digit sequences, or as a **varchar** for sequences whose size varies a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make your phone attribute as Varchar or Text to avoid this.

Phone numbers can at time also contain brackets and hyphens plus you can avoid your problem as well.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `TEXT` columns for simple things like phone numbers, nobody is going to write an essay in there ;-) it's also less efficient in terms of storage.

Comment: Ok not an essay! what I basically meant was keep it string.
I didn't mean Varchar/Text of max possible size.

whatever 10,20,30 is suitable for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data type. Int Data type will not store the starting 0's.

You can try as suggested above char or varchar

Comment: If your answer refers to the other answers, you should either comment on the main question and/or upvote the others instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integers : 06719823 = 6719823 = 0006719823
```

Save the phone as varchar if you would like to retain zeros in the begining